# Fineuploader: PHP randomized image name variable value

Tags: ajax

I am using Fineuploader for an ajax upload of changing a users profile picture, I have part of my upload.php file below:

```
function handleUpload($uploadDirectory, $replaceOldFile = FALSE){
    if (!is_writable($uploadDirectory)){
        return array('error' => "Server error. Upload directory isn't writable.");
    }

    if (!$this->file){
        return array('error' => 'No files were uploaded.');
    }

    $size = $this->file->getSize();

    if ($size == 0) {
        return array('error' => 'File is empty');
    }

    if ($size > $this->sizeLimit) {
        return array('error' => 'File is too large');
    }

    $pathinfo = pathinfo($this->file->getName());
    $filename = $pathinfo['filename'];
    //$filename = md5(uniqid());
    $ext = @$pathinfo['extension'];     // hide notices if extension is empty

    if($this->allowedExtensions && !in_array(strtolower($ext), $this->allowedExtensions)){
        $these = implode(', ', $this->allowedExtensions);
        return array('error' => 'File has an invalid extension, it should be one of '. $these . '.');
    }

    $ext = ($ext == '') ? $ext : '.' . $ext;

    if(!$replaceOldFile){
        /// don't overwrite previous files that were uploaded
        while (file_exists($uploadDirectory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename . $ext)) {
            $filename .= rand(10, 99);

        }
    }

    $this->uploadName = $filename . $ext;

    if ($this->file->save($uploadDirectory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename . $ext)){
        return array('success'=>true);

    } else {
        return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
            'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
    }

}
```

so if the image is uploaded with the same name, it creates a duplicate with a number so if asd.jpg is uploaded twice its asd44.jpg .. but I can not find how to make a variable to get the image path with random number created.

Only the initial name of the file that was uploaded. Does anyone know how to go about doing this and then making the update statement to send to database?